# How to model transient state in DDD?

Tags: domain-driven-design

I am just getting my feet wet with my first Domain-driven Design project. The project's domain model involves a bounded context that deals with collision detection of moving geometries located in a three-dimensional scene.

A central part of the business logic would be the collision detection algorithm aka the *CollisionDetector*. The algorithm must be configured with some parameters that influence its behaviour and performance. So it has some state attached making me think of it as an entity or rather an aggregate in the first place. Note that there is no requirement to persist this entity to the DB - all its parameter values are transient. Also note that there is only a single *CollisionDetector* instance present in the domain, so implementing an in-memory repository giving access to that single aggregate seems a bit overdone to me.

Summing things up we have a **stateful, transient entity with a singleton nature**.

So here is my question: While "normal" aggregates in DDD should always be accessed via repositories, how should I deal with such a unique entity instance?

- Is it advisable to use (evil) Singleton pattern here?
- Should I rather register that entity with my IOC?
- Should I implement an in-memory repository to just hold that single instance?
- Is it even reasonable to model it as an entity at all? (It doesn't need identity for it's unique.)
- Should I refactor to make it a (stateful!) domain service instead?
- Is it maybe a design smell for the domain model to have several aggregates of this type?
- I've heard about Sagas. Could they be the solution to my problem?

Please let me now if you need more context to help me with this issue.

P.S. And excuse my broken english. I'm not a native speaker.

**Edit:**

I feel I should give some further detail on `CollisionDetector` class and the state attached to it.

Maybe calling it *transient* was misleading. My intention was to point out that `CollisionDetector` will never be persisted to a storage. Its entire life is spent in active memory. Creation, modification and deletion are all part of its life cycle, persistence is not.

Another important quality of `CollisionDetector` is what I refer to as its *singleton nature* meaning that `CollisionDetector` is instanciated only once (but not necessarily using the GoF Singleton pattern). I am not sure whether the concept of identity is applicable to a singleton instance (at least there is no need for identification as there is just one), which is the only thing that keeps me from making `CollisionDetector` an entity/aggregate.

So let me shed some light on `CollisionDetector`'s state as requested by @plalx, @guillaume31 and @arootbeer.

- As mentioned already, there is a simple set of scalar parameter values used to tweak the algorithm to be either more accurate or faster. These parameters can be adjusted by the user at any time to fit his needs.
- The `CollisionDetector` keeps track of the geometries and their pose inside the scene. This is achieved via Domain Events: When one of the geometries changes its pose an event handler will automatically trigger a collision test. Likewise newly detected collisions are published by the `CollisionDetector` via Domain Events as well. Note that not all geometries are considered to be collision candidates, the user may exclude some of them from the test. Hence the `CollisionDetector` holds a blacklist of geometry ids (beeing part of its state).
- In order to detect collisions in realtime, the algorithm requires a preprocessing which is done in a separate initialization routine of `CollisionDetector`. Whenever a geometry is added to or removed from the scene, the preprocessing becomes stale and needs to be refreshed. The `CollisionDetector` is aware of that i.e. it knows whether a re-initialization is required or not.

Hope this helps!

Rethinking my question I must admit that it's merely academic. A pragmatic solution could be to make `CollisionDetector` an aggregate and just register it with the IoC container. What do you think?

Comment: This sounds like a service to me. It sounds like what you're calling "state" is actually a collection of runtime-invariant data; is that the case?

Comment: What kind of state the CollisionDetector will carry and what kind of invariants should be enforced? Should the CollisionDetector state be durable (should you be able to restore it from disk)? What about concurrency?

Comment: @Pille Just looking at your question, this doesn't seem like a problem domain where you would typically apply DDD tactical patterns (Aggregate, Entity, etc.), even if strategically the Bounded Context was discovered through a DDD approach.

Comment: @arootbeer, @plalx and @guillaume31 I have edited my question to add more detail on `CollisionDetector`'s state.

Answer (score 2):

> The algorithm must be **configured** with some parameters that influence its behaviour and performance. So it has some **state** attached making me think of it as an entity or rather an aggregate in the first place. *(emphasis mine)*

I don't consider the configuration of the `CollisionDetector` to be its state. It is only configuration and cannot change once the `CollisionDetector` is instantiated, so it is something much simpler than mutable state that you typically find in entities.

As a consequence, I clearly consider the `CollisionDetector` a domain service. This means you should handle it as follows:

**Register the `CollisionDetector` service in IoC. The configuration of the `CollisionDetector` is probably considered domain logic, so it could make sense to instantiate the `CollisionDetector` in a `CollisionDetectorFactory`. If that's the approach you take, register the factory in IoC instead.** In any case, make sure the clients of the `CollisionDetector` don't have to know about its configuration.

By the way, don't use singletons (i.e. the GoF singleton pattern) when you work with IoC. You can always register a service as single instance, which has the same effect as the singleton pattern, but avoids its problems.

Comment: I totally agree with you and @arootbeer that `CollisionDetector` should be a service if its configuration parameters were just construction arguments. But actually they are not. `CollisionDetector`'s state is mutable. It can change over time, triggered by the user or by domain events. The only thing that holds me from making it an entity is that there is no need for identity because of it's singleton nature.

Comment: @Pille what kind of state would it have ? How does it change over time ? And why do you call it "transient" ?